# Spring integration - recipient-list-router timeout

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Anyone used Spring recipient-list-router with timeout attribute?

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="customRouter" input-channel="routingChannel"
        timeout="1234"
        ignore-send-failures="true"
        apply-sequence="true">
  <int:recipient channel="channel1"/>
  <int:recipient channel="channel2"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

**timeout** : 
The timeout attribute specifies the maximum amount of time in milliseconds to wait, when sending Messages to the target Message Channels. By default the send operation will block indefinitely.

**I am trying to figure what would be a good amount of time to *wait* before moving on to next channel.**

Comment: What is your output channel? if its not a queue (finite size) then you dont need to put any timeout.

Comment: Its a queue channel, I am wondering what is a good amount of time to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it sounds like:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="timeout" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Specify the maximum amount of time in milliseconds to wait
                when sending Messages to the target MessageChannels if blocking
                is possible (e.g. a bounded queue channel that is currently full).
                By default the send will block indefinitely.
                DEPRECATED in favor of 'send-timeout' for consistency with other elements.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Pay attention to the `bounded queue channel` phrase. So, this is applied via `MessagingTemplate` only when your target channel is restricted by the size `QueueChannel`.

So, if your channel is `DirectChannel`, there is no any possibility to *wait*. Just because the `AbstractMessageRouter` is as a simple `loop` logic and the `send` and therefore handling process is performed on the same thread.

Comment: Its a queue channel, I am wondering what is a good amount of time to wait?

Comment: Yeah... It's some reasonable time to wait before raising TimeoutException. Consider the same scenario with the HTTP Client or any TCP/IP interactions. I'd say that the better way to take a look is the sender: how it is appropriate for him to wait back from you. So, it's really depends on the target application and that option doesn't fit some general recipe as you would like to hear from us.

Comment: @PrasadParavatha: A good amount time to wait would be where you do not block it for too long and you do not drop packages too soon :))

Comment: Thank you guys :-)